# SQL - Double (or Triple) counting stats when using JOIN or SUM

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, distinct

I'm quit new to SQL and read a lot on StackOverflow for now. I'm using the Google Ads Data Transfer in BigQuery.

Got a problem with doubling / tripling the amount of **impressions, clicks and spend** with this formula:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId AS klant_id,
  AccountDescriptiveName AS klant_naam,
  campaignStatsOverall.Date AS datum,
  EXTRACT(DAY
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS dag_in_de_maand,
  EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS maand,
  EXTRACT(QUARTER
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS kwartaal,
  EXTRACT(YEAR
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS jaar,
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY)
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS weeknummer,
  SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Clicks) AS klikken,
  SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Impressions) AS vertoningen,
  SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Conversions) AS conversies,
  ROUND(SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Cost)/1000000,2) AS spend
FROM
  `mvhmedia.ads_mcc_mvhmedia_raw_data.p_Customer_7834578801` AS customerData
LEFT JOIN
  `mvhmedia.ads_mcc_mvhmedia_raw_data.p_CampaignBasicStats_7834578801` AS campaignStatsOverall
ON
  campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId = customerData.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE
  DATE(customerData._PARTITIONTIME) > '2020-04-30'
GROUP BY
  klant_id,
  klant_naam,
  datum
ORDER BY
  datum DESC,
  klant_naam
```

When I don't use the math in the SELECT-area, the numbers are right.
This is giving me a lot of rows in the table (due to the DISTINCT and SUM):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT AccountDescriptiveName AS klant_naam,
  campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId AS klant_id,
  campaignStatsOverall.Date AS datum,
  EXTRACT(DAY
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS dag_in_de_maand,
  EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS maand,
  EXTRACT(QUARTER
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS kwartaal,
  EXTRACT(YEAR
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS jaar,
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY)
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS weeknummer,
  campaignStatsOverall.Clicks AS klikken,
  campaignStatsOverall.Impressions AS vertoningen,
  ROUND(campaignStatsOverall.Conversions,3) AS conversies,
  ROUND(campaignStatsOverall.Cost/1000000,2) AS spend
FROM
  `mvhmedia.ads_mcc_mvhmedia_raw_data.p_Customer_7834578801` AS customerData
LEFT JOIN
  `mvhmedia.ads_mcc_mvhmedia_raw_data.p_CampaignBasicStats_7834578801` AS campaignStatsOverall
ON
  campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId = customerData.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE
  DATE(customerData._PARTITIONTIME) > '2020-04-30'
  AND campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId = customerData.ExternalCustomerId
GROUP BY
  klant_id,
  klant_naam,
  datum,
  klikken,
  vertoningen,
  conversies,
  spend
ORDER BY
  datum DESC,
  klant_naam
```

Think I'm doing something wrong with either DISTINCT, the SUM or the LEFT JOIN.

Hope someone can help me out here.

What it should be:

| klantnaam | klikken | vertoningen | conversies | spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client a | 112 | 2599 | 7.0 | 33.08 |
| client b | 66 | 3223 | 6.0 | 26.6 |

What it gives me (tripling):

| klantnaam | klikken | vertoningen | conversies | spend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client a | 336 | 7797 | 21.0 | 99.26 |
| client b | 198 | 9669 | 18.0 | 79.8 |

Seems like it's tripling the data.

Comment: 1) You rarely never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY. (I raise my eyebrows when I see such, and wonder what's going on.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! And provide sample table data and the expected result - [mcve].

Comment: Adding what the results should be without showing what the souce data is, is like asking us to perform real magic.  (Did you read the link Jarl gave you?)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a `LEFT JOIN`, it seems you have a 1-n junction between `CustomerData` and `campaignStatsOverall`. That means the `SUM` will sum *n* times the linked rows from `campaignStatsOverall`for each customer.

To avoid that, i suggest you to see for windowed function. With `SUM`, you can go with something like  :

```
 SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Clicks) OVER (PARTITION BY customerData.ExternalCustomerId) AS klikken,
```

Note that you can't generaly use windowed function with a `GROUP BY` clause. So if you need to distinct/group the rows from `CustomerData`, you should do that in a subquery (see `WITH`clause) and then apply a `SELECT` on the related subquery with the windowed `SUM`.

I urge you to always check carefully your table junctions for potential cartesian effects, you should always rely on primary key junctions or well defined cartesian junctions.

**EDIT:** Windowed functions (also called analytic functions) documentation for Google BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts

**EDIT2:** As there's no comments, i guess OP is looking for the full script. Here it is :

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId AS klant_id,
  AccountDescriptiveName AS klant_naam,
  campaignStatsOverall.Date AS datum,
  EXTRACT(DAY
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS dag_in_de_maand,
  EXTRACT(MONTH
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS maand,
  EXTRACT(QUARTER
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS kwartaal,
  EXTRACT(YEAR
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS jaar,
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY)
  FROM
    campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS weeknummer,
  SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Clicks) OVER (PARTITION BY customerData.ExternalCustomerId, customerData.AccountDescriptiveName, campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS klikken,
  SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Impressions) OVER (PARTITION BY customerData.ExternalCustomerId, customerData.AccountDescriptiveName, campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS vertoningen,
  SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Conversions) OVER (PARTITION BY customerData.ExternalCustomerId, customerData.AccountDescriptiveName, campaignStatsOverall.Date) AS conversies,
  ROUND(SUM(campaignStatsOverall.Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY customerData.ExternalCustomerId, customerData.AccountDescriptiveName, campaignStatsOverall.Date)/1000000,2) AS spend
FROM
  `mvhmedia.ads_mcc_mvhmedia_raw_data.p_Customer_7834578801` AS customerData
LEFT JOIN
  `mvhmedia.ads_mcc_mvhmedia_raw_data.p_CampaignBasicStats_7834578801` AS campaignStatsOverall
ON
  campaignStatsOverall.ExternalCustomerId = customerData.ExternalCustomerId
WHERE
  DATE(customerData._PARTITIONTIME) > '2020-04-30'
ORDER BY
  datum DESC,
  klant_naam
```

As you see, using windowed functions means no more `GROUP BY` clause *here*.  The `DISTINCT` is now meaningful as its goal is to two distinguish records for which `klant_id`, `klant_naam` and `datum` are provided. The *partitioned sums* of  `klikken`, `spend` etc. are just **calculated for this three**, so they can be distinguished within this three on the `DISTINCT` output.

On another note, if `ExternalCustomerId`  is a key for *campaignStatsOverall*, you could remove `AccountDescriptiveName` from `PARTITION BY`/`GROUP BY` operations.